# How to set as default this format of current time and date on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mobiscroll

I am using a jQuery script that let me choose a date and time. However on page's load the textbox does not have any date+time in it. I would like to display the current date and time like the format below.

**2012-07-25 15:10**

```
        $(function () {
            var now = new Date();

            $('#date').scroller({
                preset: 'datetime',
                minDate: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()),
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                timeFormat: 'HH:ii',

            }).val('what should I write here?');
        });
```

Comment: Are you using the Mobiscroll plugin? Or what kind of plugin?

Comment: @bažmegakapa Yes it's the mobiscroll plugin

Comment: Could you simply use the `.setDate()` method?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want:

```
$('#date').val($.scroller.formatDate('yy-mm-dd HH:ii', now));
```

or simply:

```
$('#date').scroller('setDate', now, true);
```

Comment: @bažmegakapa Probably not. I was answering the literal question of 'what should I write here?'.

Comment: I get it. Then my question rephrased: So should one write that there?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/) states that you can set the date using the `setDate` method.

> ```
> .scroller('setDate', date, fill, time)
> ```
>
> If a preset is selected sets the scroller date/time from the date
>   parameter passed as a Date object. If the 'fill' parameter is true,
>   the associated input field is also updated with the new value. The
>   'time' parameter specifies the duration of the animation in seconds to
>   scroll the wheels to the new date. There is no animation, if 'time' is
>   not specified

So I imagine something like this should work:

```
var now = new Date();

$('#date')
    .scroller({
        preset: 'datetime',
        minDate: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(),
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'HH:ii',
    })
    .scroller('setDate', now, true);
```